# You must choose a committee of 8 people containing at least 2 men. There are 9 men and 11 women to choose from. How many committees are there?

Tags: combinatorics

You must choose a committee of 8 people containing at least 2 men.

There are 9 men and 11 women to choose from.

How many committees are there?

I reached this answer but it seems a little too simple for what was a ($5$) mark question in a previous exam

${9\choose 8}\cdot{11\choose 6}$

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, how did you reached that answer? what was the thinking process?

Comment: the committee has a total of 8 slots. Men can take up all 8 hence the ${9\choose 8}$.
The women on the other hand can only take up 6 slots as 2 of the slots have to be filled by men so that's where I got the ${11\choose 6}$.

So together I get:
${9\choose 8}\cdot{11\choose 6}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you aren't considering that the committee could be all men, or $7$ men and $1$ women, or ... .

The easiest way to do this I think is to subtract the inadmissible committees from the total.  There are $\binom{20}{8}$ ways to choose $8$ people from $20$.  We must subtract the $\binom{11}8$ committees that comprise only women, and the $\binom91\binom{11}7$ with exactly one man.  The answer is $$\binom{20}{8}-\binom{11}8 -\binom91\binom{11}7$$

Comment: Thank you very much this makes sense and really clears up how to use this method.